# Unmarshalling of XML key-value pair in java object

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, jaxb, unmarshalling

Unmarshall XML key value part into java object using jaxb.  I have tried using map adapter, but I'm not able to do it.

```
<ACCOUNT_CHANGES>
    <TYPE value="Active" />
    <RECORD>
        <SUBSCRIPTION>
            <INFO key="aaa">
                <![CDATA[042]]>
            </INFO>
            <INFO key="bbb">
                <![CDATA[45]]>
            </INFO>
            <INFO key="uuid">
                <![CDATA[d9a7e94c-0a9d-c745-82e9-980877cc5043]]>
            </INFO>
            <INFO key="ccc">
                <![CDATA[Active]]>
            </INFO>
            <INFO key="companyname">
                <![CDATA[ltd]]>
            </INFO>
        </SUBSCRIPTION>
    </RECORD>
</ACCOUNT_CHANGES>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an adapter to do that, but as I understand your requirement it is not necessary. If you simply want to unmarshall into an object, not into a Map, you can do the following:

Starting from the root:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "ACCOUNT_CHANGES")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class AccountChanges {

    @XmlElement(name = "TYPE")
    private Type type;

    @XmlElement(name = "RECORD")
    private Record record;

}
```

Let's take Type out of the way:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Type {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String value;
}
```

Then the record:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Record {

    @XmlElement(name = "SUBSCRIPTION")
    private Subscription subscription;
}
```

And the subscription:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Subscription {

    @XmlElement(name = "INFO")
    private List<Info> infoList;
}
```

Info has your key as attribute and then some value. It would look like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Info {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String key;

    @XmlValue
    private String value;

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

This will unmarshal your xml, and info keys and values will be in the fields. In case you want the key and value in a map, you can use an adapter.

The adapter looks like this:

```
public class MyMapAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Info, Map<String, String>> {

    private HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> unmarshal(Info v) throws Exception {
        hashMap.put(v.getKey(), v.getValue());
        return hashMap;
    }

    @Override
    public Info marshal(Map<String, String> v) throws Exception {
        // do here actions for marshalling if u also marshal
        return null;
    }
}
```

And you will change the Subscription to use the adapter and have map as a field:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Subscription {

    @XmlElement(name = "INFO")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MyMapAdapter.class)
    private Map<String, String> infoMap;
}
```

Two ways, both unmarshal your xml payload.

Cheers

Comment: thanks for the detail explanation.Love the adapter approach.

Comment: @NiladriChanda happy to help :)